# Excel VBA logic not working

Tags: vba, excel, ms-office

There are two sheets with company name in first column and item price is 1st row. Now i need if company name is matched than it should check row and update the values

```
Sub addition()
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim a As Integer
    Dim b As Integer

    For i = 2 To 15
        For j = 2 To 15
            If Sheet1.Cells(i, 1) = Sheet1.Cells(j, 1) Then
                For a = 2 To 5
                    For b = 2 To 5
                        If Sheet1.Cells(1, a) = Sheet2.Cells(1, b) Then
                                Sheet1.Cells(i, a) = Sheet2.Cells(j, b) + Sheet1.Cells(i, a)

                        End If
                     Next b
                Next a

            End If
        Next j
    Next i

End Sub
```

But in some row logic works others it does not.

Comment: `If Sheet1.Cells(i, 1) = Sheet1.Cells(j, 1) Then` should one of those be Sheet2? Maybe `Sheet2.Cells(j, 1)` ...?

Comment: Your logic does not work? In what way? Please make the effort to actually explain the issue.

Comment: Some sample data might also be helpful.

Comment: Thank you @Jeeped it worked

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 2):

```
For i = 2 To 15
    For j = 2 To 15
        If Sheet1.Cells(i, 1) = Sheet1.Cells(j, 1) Then
            ...
```

The above code is going to find 14 matches since i and j are the same value 14 times and they both refer to the same worksheet, same column.

Since you use j to refer to a row on Sheet2 later in the code, the above should most likely be closer to this.

```
For i = 2 To 15
    For j = 2 To 15
        If Sheet1.Cells(i, 1) = Sheet2.Cells(j, 1) Then
            ...
```

However, even if switching to Sheet2.Cells(j, 1) repairs the logic, do everything for everything else is very inefficient. You could reduce the loops with Exit For statements that did not continue looking for matches after one had been found. Furthe to the one-match-and-done is a match on the column's values which negates the inner loop entirely.

```
Sub addition()
    Dim i As long, a As long
    Dim j As variant, b as variant

    For i = 2 To 15
        i = application.match(Sheet1.Cells(i, 1), Sheet2.Cells(2, 1).resize(14, 1), 0)
        if not iserror(i) then
            For a = 2 To 5
                b = application.match(Sheet1.Cells(1, a), Sheet2.Cells(1, 2).resize(1, 4), 0)
                if not iserror(b) then
                    Sheet1.Cells(i, a) = Sheet2.Cells(j, b) + Sheet1.Cells(i, a)
                End If
            Next a
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```